# Error creating new process c++

Tags: c++, api, process

After a lot of time spent in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), I created this part of code that open a file called `system.exe`.

The code is compiled without any error but the file doesn't start. I've checked if the file exist, it exist but doesn't startup!

Why? Thanks

```
void start(string path){
    STARTUPINFO Startupinf;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION Processinfo;
    cout<<path;
    if(!CreateProcess(path.c_str(),NULL,NULL,NULL,FALSE,NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,NULL,path.c_str(),&Startupinf,&Processinfo)){
        cout<<"\n\n\nERROR 3x02";
    }
}
```

Comment: Check value of `::GetLastError()`

Comment: If you are starting a process 'path.c_str()', then your current directory is not `path.c_str()` which would be an executable - right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize:

1. Always check what `GetLastError()` returns after calling `CreateProcess()`.
2. If you are starting a process `path.c_str()`, then your current directory is not `path.c_str()` which would be an executable - right?
3. Initialize `StartupInfo` and `ProcessInfo`:

   ```
   PROCESS_INFORMATION Processinfo; ZeroMemory(&Processinfo, sizeof(Processinfo));
   STARTUPINFO StartupInf; ZeroMemory(&StartupInf, sizeof(StartupInf));
   StartupInf.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
   ```

Comment: 1) i don't know the usage of GetLastError but i added it at the end of the void
2)yeah, right, path.c_str() is not the pat of this program
3)At the start i've initialized Startupinf and Processinfo but still give me error!

Comment: @MarioValentino read value from GetLastError() and then check its error code to learn what have you done wrong

Comment: How i can read it?
Console gives to me process returned 0 (0x00)

Comment: type `cout << ::GetLastError();` inside your if

Comment: He says to me Error 267

Comment: This is ERROR_DIRECTORY, maybe because your current directory argument is not a directory path

Comment: the path is in this format: path = "C:\\Users\\Mario\\Documents\\c++\\hook\\bin\\Debug\\system.exe"; this is a path i think

Comment: the program read a registry value that contain the path (C:\Users\Mario\Documents\c++\hook\bin\Debug\system.exe) and assign this value to the variable path

Comment: `path` contains a path to an executable file, not a directory, so you **cannot** pass `path.c_str()` to the `lpCurrentDirectory` parameter of `CreateProcess()`, otherwise you get the `ERROR_DIRECTORY` error ("The directory name is invalid"). Either pass NULL to inherit the calling process's current directory, or else specify a real directory. Such as copying path` to another variable and stripping off the `system.exe` portion from it.